# Cannot connect to MySQL database on home computer

Tags: mysql, database-connection

**Description**

I've downloaded [MySQL installer 5.7.21 for Windows](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/5.7.html) onto my windows 10 machine and setup a server on port 3306 (I see the server status is "Running" within MySQL workbench, and I've also confirmed this by looking in Windows "Services" settings).

I created a database on this server with a dummy table. I have no issue executing sql statements.

Within the Windows firewall I set both "mysql_port_3306" and "Port 3306" as "Allowed App"s.

In MySQL Workbench I connected to the server and issued the (deprecated) command

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'username'@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

with `username`, `1.2.3.4`, and `password` replaced by my username, the IP address of my laptop (a different cpu than the one I'm setting this server up on), and the password.

On the laptop I created a new connection within MySQL Workbench with the following connection parameters:

- Connection Method: Standard (TCP/IP)
- Hostname: the full name of the computer hosting the database (which is also the server host name)
- Port 3306
- Username and Password: the same values set in the SQL statement above

**Problem**

After doing all this when I test the connection on my laptop the program goes into "Not Responding" status for a short time then becomes usable again without giving results for the connection test. If I try to connect I receive the following error:

> Cannot Connect to Database Server

Are there other steps I need to take to connect to the server I've created? Most of the guides I read have to do with installing the workbench, starting the server, or connecting to a server which is already configured to allow remote connections, but I feel I'm missing a step.

Thanks!

Comment: Most likely suspect: firewall problems (disable the windows firewall for testing purposes) or name resolution (use the ip address of your server instead of the server name).

Comment: Thanks @Solarflare. I had tried with the IP address as well, and this did not work. I just tried again after disabling windows firewall on both machines and still was unable to connect. I feel like I'm missing a step for configuring the server on the machine running it ... is there anything of that nature you can see here? Is there a more basic way to test that?

Comment: You may also want to check if your configuration `my.ini` contains a "bind-address", and remove it (add a `#` infront of it to comment it out), same for "skip-networking".

Comment: @Solarflare: Looking in the `my.ini` file at "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7" I do not find the string "bind" anywhere, and although there is a section for the "skip-networking", there is no variable set in this section.

Comment: What do youi mean by "section"? If "skip-networking" is listed somewhere, comment it out by adding a "#" infront of it (or remove the line, you will not need it). Both values (bind-address and skip-networking) would not be enabled in a default installation, but might have somehow made it to your installation. Apart from that: try some port scanner (e.g. nmap) to check if the mysql port is reachable from your client. You seem to have a network problem somewhere, but it is hard to guess.